# Designing Java unit test with static calls inside method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, testng

I'm trying to create a unit test for a class that has a method that uses Request.Post method from apache's fluent-hc library (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Request.html).

The thing is I don't want it to send an actual request every time I run the test suit, even less if its a unit test, not an integration one. But I don't know how to make my way around that.

I'm new in the testing world and for what I've read most of the time when you can't test something, there's a problem with the design of the class.

```
public class HttpRequestSenderServiceImpl implements RequestSenderService {

@Override
public Response sendRequest(String address, String messageBody) throws IOException {
    Request request = Request.Post(address).bodyString(messageBody, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response response = request.execute();

    return response;
}
```

}

I'm using Spring framework and Spring-Test, Mockito and TestNG as testing tools. I'll really appreciate if you could at least point me in the right direction, any material to read, book, video, anything. I just want to learn to do it the right way.

I've found some "solutions" to my problem but they all uses PowerMockito, and for what I've read is bad for you because allows mocking static methods, constructors, etc, which translate to bad coding practices, which is what I'm trying to avoid here.

Comment: so you want to mock a static method, right?

Comment: Not exactly, what I want to know is how could I had designed that class in a way that I wouldn't need to do that. Like, if it were you who needed to make a post call, how would you had design it?

Comment: I do not think, mocking a static method is bad at all. But if you really like to avoid, is this the method, that pais to test? I think, this method isn't worth to have any unit test, since you don't have any business logic inside, you just "facade" a spring post call. In my opinion, even this method requires the integration test insted.

Comment: I also think, you have a good sw architecture - the call of a framework `post` method is inside `RequestSenderService`, and all your business classes use this class and thus are loosely coupled. For them, you should write unit tests to test their logic and mock `RequestSenderService `, but not for this "wrapper".

Comment: at unit testing, you "expect" some behavior and also some result (or exception) of the method at specific inputs. But what would you test here? In the case, you don't use "real" framework (no integration test), the result is always just some `Response` mock, but in your method under test nothing happened to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your purpose the problem is more in the apache's fluent-hc `Request.Post`, that is static and not mock friendly, than in your code.

You can use [Executor](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/http/client/fluent/Executor.html) and mock execute method, or if you want to use `Request.Post` wrap it in another low level service interface and use it:

```
interface RequestSender {
      Response send(String addr,msgBody)
}

class RequestSenderImpl implements RequestSender {
    public Response send(String addr,msgBody) {
       Request request = Request.Post(address).bodyString(messageBody,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
       Response response = request.execute();
       return response;
    }
}
```

That way you can easily mock the code even without mockito.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Sorry I couldn't be more specific, I'm just trying to learn and learn it right, and reading all over that having to use PowerMockito is a symptom of bad code practices kind of put me down a little bit because is what I've been trying to avoid since the start. Regarding the why, I'm just aiming to have the most amount of coverage possible, I'm still to develop a judgement to whether I should test something or not.

Thank you very much for your time and answer, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

[@lujop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269454/lujop%20@lujop) has provided a suggestion for the problem mentioned which I believe is one way to do it.

However, as to earlier statement of using mocking frameworks, I don't it is entirely a bad practice all the time. Consider the suggestion from [@lujop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269454/lujop%20@lujop), you would probably end up using a [Test Double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) to unit-test RequestSenderImpl and it's business logic.

But there would be a class, say - `FluentHCRequestSender` - which would be responsible for actually making a call to `Request.Post`. Now if you were writing UTs for all your classes, you would have to use mocking framework to test `FluentHCRequestSender` to ensure that this class is using the right API.

There is a place for tests using mocking frameworks. But generally, it justs points to a bad design if you end up using mocking frameworks if your dependencies are classes that you, your team or your organization has created.

And to answer your question of resources that can help you in writing better UT and code in general,

[SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) - This is probably one thing that is always in the back 
   of my mind while writing code.

[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B005OYHF0A/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1) which has served me well.

[Test Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) - During my practice, not very easy to
   strictly follow in your day-to-day routine, but it at least forces me
   not to put-off my UTs and work on them simultaneously with my actual
   classes (if not before).

[Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) - Grab hold of a good design pattern book/video
   if a library is accessible to you or buy one. The concepts might seem
   intimidating, but I find some of them really useful in my day-to-day
   work and especially while writing UTs.

But personally, the best way to learn to see existing code in your code base and see what's good and what can be improved. I have found looking and understanding code written by people who do good design much more useful than any of the books.

Hope this long winding post helps !!

PS - Kudos on trying to do the right way. Sometimes it is not said often, although it should be.